# How to create an if statement for jQuery, click event

Tags: jquery, click, onclick

I do have a css class name ".className"
How to create an if statement wherein if the user does not click .className it will alert.
for example:

```
if (click != $('.className')) {
   alert("You did not click className");
}
```

I know that my code is incorrect. How to do it? Btw, this is similar to an outside click.
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!$(this).hasClass('className')) {
        alert("You did not click className!");
    }
});
```

***demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yaqLs/***

---

EDIT: If by "outside clicks" you mean not just links then,

```
$("*").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    if (!$(this).hasClass('className')) {
        alert("You did not click className!");
    }
});
```

***demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yaqLs/1/***